# how i can change color of viewport region extjs 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How I can change the individual region background color of viewport extjs 4.
Here is my code.

```
{
    region: 'south',
    title: 'South Panel',
    collapsible: true,
    html: 'Information goes here',
    split: true,
    height: 100,
    minHeight: 100
}, {
    region: 'east',
    title: 'East Panel',
    collapsible: true,
    split: true,
    width: 150
}
```

Now tell me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign a class to the body using the bodyCls config then set the background-color via css. Alternatively, you can set the bodyStyle inline to a css string:

```
bodyCls: 'foo'
// or
bodyStyle: 'background-color: red;'
```

To do it dynamically, you can set the style on the body:

```
myPanel.body.setStyle('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: how i can apply from function like `Ext.get('test').setStyle('name','prop');`